# Python "Serialize" not defined

Tags: python-3.7

can you help me figure out how to fix this issue or how to declare the variable? This is only part of my code but the section where the error is occurring.

```
 def send_message(self, message, source = "Python Client", type = serialize.Message.INFO_MESSAGE):
     md = Command.RTDE_TEXT_MESSAGE
    fmt = '>B%dsB%dsB' % (len(message), len(source))
    payload = struct.pack(fmt, len(message), message, len(source), source, type)
    return self.__sendall(cmd, payload)
```

And here is the error I'm getting

```
File "..\rtde\rtde.py", line 187, in RTDE
  def send_message(self, message, source = "Python Client", type = serialize.Message.INFO_MESSAGE):
NameError: name 'serialize' is not defined
```

Comment: Is `serialize` imported?

Comment: Yes, its a program that is called and in the same parent folder as rtde.rtde

Comment: Did you checked this https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html